# Get google map markers according to category

Tags: android, google-maps

I am new to google maps on android. My application needs a method that will return a marker with a color that will correspond to an item category. Does android offer a set of retrievable markers? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, android does offer. You must be referring to BitmapDescriptorFactory.

```
//This function is used to determine the color of markers according to its category
public static BitmapDescriptor getMarkerIconByCategory(String englishCategory){

    if(englishCategory.equals("hotels"))
        return BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE);
    else if(englishCategory.equals("restaurants")){
        return BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED);
    }else if(englishCategory.equals("spas")){
        return BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ROSE);
    }else if(englishCategory.equals("spots")){
        return BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN);
    }else if(englishCategory.equals("tours")){
        return BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE);
    }else{
        return BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_VIOLET);
    }
}
```

Comment: If it answered your question, can you please check the tick?